# Eclipse console link, duplicate filenames in package structure, which is opened?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have an application that has two classes called "Service" in two different places in the package structure. The logging outputs the file and line number like this, eg: (Service.java:102)
This becomes a clickable link in the console output in Eclipse. Normally, these links are great because you can find exactly of where the output was printed from with a single click.
But now I have two Service.java files, doing two entirely different things, and they're in a different place in the package structure. I can't rename either of them.
When I click on the link, it takes me to the wrong java file, even when the correct java file is open in the editor.

I've searched around, but I can't find the answer. Is there a way to tell Eclipse which java file to consider first? Or a way to tell which package to look in first? Something, anything, to make these clickable links useful again?

Comment: Tell us more about the *logging*. What tool are you using to log?

Comment: It's a home brew with features to make it easier to comprehend more information quicker. I wish I could contribute it, but right now can't.

Answer (score 1):

i know three ways how to print a clickable class link in the console output.

**First way:**

Just print the class name inside the parentheses: `System.out.println("(Service.java:42)");`

This is simple method and will work if you are not using ambiguous class names. Since Eclipse console does not have informations required to decide which file should be opened, i guess it will open the first occurence.

**Second way:**

In your case. I would do it by using  `StackTraceElement` to print the class name.
That way:

```
StackTraceElement element = new StackTraceElement(
            "Service",                          // Class name
            "myFunnyMethodName",                // Method name
            Service.class.getName()+".java",    // Path to File
            2);                                 // line number


System.out.println(element);
```

**Third way:**

If you don't want to create `StackTraceElement` you can get it from you current thread.

Example:

```
System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1]);
```

**EDIT:**

The other option is to try the [Grep Console Plugin for Eclipse](http://marian.schedenig.name/projects/grep-console/). You can define your own Expressions with Link, Color, Popup etc...

Comment: It's part of the custom logging system, where I grab the stack trace, and discard the StackTraceElements that are part of the logging system itself. I then print *all* the remaining locations, like this: (SomeService.java:123) (Service.java:102) (BlockingQueue.java:321). Eclipse opens the wrong Service java file every time, even though the correct one is open in the editor. So that could be considered a bug or feature that ought to be addressed by the Eclipse guyss, IMO.
But is there already a feature that helps control the resolving order?

Comment: I don't think this plugin will solve Mike's issue, it's more about console enhancing through style and other goodies.

Comment: I've been using grep-console for a while myself. I love how I can make it color lines with certain keywords. eg. SEVERE in red, client in light green, server in light blue. Logging is otherwise one sequential pile of goo, where you can't see the trees through the forest.
Funny thing is logging is in principle hierarchy oriented, but it's always presenting as one sequential goo. Where are the better log viewers?

Comment: In General I fill in, I'm guessing "Service:([0-9]+)", thinking that in the link, the line number would refer to group 1 in the regular expression.
I've first tried with another keyword, and without the line number. The word isn't becoming clickable in the console.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your logger is configured like this to ouput a log like that `(Service.java:102)` :

```
(%F:%L)
```

> %F : Used to output the file name where the logging request was issued.
>
> %L : Used to output the line number from where the logging request was issued.

Try to used `%l` instead

> %l : Used to output location information of the caller which generated the logging event.

**EDIT**

this solution does not seem to work well, it prints

```
com.x.y.z.MyClass.myMethod(MyClass.java:36)
```

=> the link is only on the classname, same issue.

But using the following pattern will work

```
(%C.java:%L)
```

It will print a full link like this :

```
(com.x.y.z.MyClass.java:36)
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have a custom logging system that prints to stdout (and saves to a log file). I use the StackTraceElement to extract the file name and line number from.
I could change that code to include the location information, like you suggest, but that would make the output verbose. Verbose is bad, because I'm not just printing one location, but the whole stack chain. This way, for every log statement, I see what the whole call chain is, eg:
(SomeService.java:123) (Service.java:102) (BlockingQueue.java:321)
I'd rather control Eclipse's resolving order.

Comment: Weird, this bug seems to be fixed since a long time : https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=166113
Maybe it's only fixed in stack trace, not in logging entries

Comment: I saw that and other stacktrace related bugs as well.
I haven't reported anything on the Eclipse site yet. Perhaps I should sign up and report this.
I've ran into this a few times before where I could rename a class, but this time I can't rename the class. It might take a while before seeing a fix materialize I bet.